# Understanding Code behind auto closing and saving in excel

Tags: vba, excel

The Goal: I'm trying to auto close out of workbooks for the reports I update as there are users who have them open, and forget to close them at night. I've set the auto close time to 12am.

Question 1: So I already have a couple of solutions for this problem. I found answers through a smattering of searches on google, and combined a few pieces of code to get exactly what I wanted. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to have the excel vba auto save & close in just one Module or ThisWorkbook. Essentially keeping all the code in one place.

Question 2: I know that the 1st and 2nd macro work I'm wondering which is more efficient and clean, and why?

1ST MACRO

' Insert into ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Static SchedSave

  If SchedSave <> 0 Then
    Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , False
  End If

  SchedSave = TimeValue("09:29:00") ' Insert Desired time in Military
  Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , True

End Sub
```

---

' Insert into module

```
Sub SaveWork()
  ThisWorkbook.Save
  ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

---

2ND MACRO

' Insert into ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Reset
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Reset
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Reset
End Sub
```

---

' Insert into Module

```
Sub Reset()
  Static SchedSave
  If SchedSave <> 0 Then
    Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , False
  End If
  SchedSave = TimeValue("12:00:00") ' 12AM
  Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , True
End Sub

Sub SaveWork()
  ThisWorkbook.Save
  ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Also posted: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-q...ml#post3830083 (This is where I got help to get the 1st Macro to work)

Comment: I would go for solution 2, as you then can call the Reset() from several places ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Answer (score 0):

I might not be a genius but nothing prevents you to put the "module-code" in "thisworkbook".

I don't see why you have to call the "Reset" Macro each time the workbook is opened, each time a worksheet is changed and... well isn't a worksheet activated as soon as you open a workbook? I'd say the 1st is the best.

EDIT: Lol I didn't see the unformatted 'insert this into thisworkbook

Comment: In regards to putting the module-code in ThisWorkbook, are you suggesting that I change the code to possibly look like:

'Insert ThisWorkbook
<code>
Sub Workbook_Open()
Static SchedSave
  If SchedSave <> 0 Then
    Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , False
  End If
  SchedSave = TimeValue("09:29:00") ' Insert Desired time in Military
  Application.OnTime SchedSave, "SaveWork", , True
End Sub

Sub SaveWork()
  ThisWorkbook.Save
  ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
</code>

Comment: if I correctly understood, that is exactly the first possibility which, IMHO is the best one